# Xpath base64Decode not working in Wso2Esb 4.8.1

Tags: xpath, wso2, base64, xpath-2.0, wso2-esb

I'm receiving a base64 stream that I need to decode.
I'm doing some research but I'm stuck, this is my code:

```
<outSequence>
     <property name="cadena" value="Hola mundo" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <property name="cadena64"
               expression="base64Encode(get-property('cadena'))"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>
     <property 
               name="cadenaASCII"
               expression="syn:base64Decode(syn:get-property('cadena64'))"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>
     <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
          {"cadena":"$1",
            "cadena64":"$2",
            "cadenaASCII":"$3",
          }
        </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('cadena')"/>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('cadena64')"/>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('cadenaASCII')"/>
        </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
```

I enabled Xpath 2.0 by uncommenting the line

```
synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true
```

located at $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory (and restarting the service).

This is the error I get:

```
Evaluation of the XPath expression syn:base64Decode(syn:get-property('cadena64')) resulted in an error  More TID[-1234] [ESB] [2019-03-04 19:27:23,359] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath} - Evaluation of the XPath expression syn:base64Decode(syn:get-property('cadena64')) resulted in an error net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator.compile(XPathEvaluator.java:378) org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.evaluateDOMXPath(SynapseXPath.java:529) org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.stringValueOf(SynapseXPath.java:364) org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.getResultValue(PropertyMediator.java:302) org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.mediate(PropertyMediator.java:96) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77) org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47) org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:268) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:488) org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:170) org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:225) org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only encode is supported/implemented in 4.8.1 otherwise as already mentioned an option is to upgrade the esb. The following worked for me in 4.8.1

```
   <property name="contentBase64" expression="//t:Content" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

<script language="js"><![CDATA[importPackage(Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.binary); var log = mc.getServiceLog();      log.info("1");var c = mc.getProperty("contentBase64");log.info("2:"+c);var bc = Base64.decodeBase64(c);log.info("3:"+bc);  var result = "";  for(var i = 0; i                                                                                                                               
                                             < bc.length; ++i){     result+= (String.fromCharCode(bc[i]));  }   log.info("result:"+result);      mc.setProperty("contentDecoded", result);]]></script>
```

The decoded content can the be accessed in the property "contentDecoded".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking forward to upgrade the version, but meanwhile your code works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The error you quoted contains a poorly formatted stack trace:

```
Evaluation of the XPath expression syn:base64Decode(syn:get-property('cadena64')) resulted in an error  
More TID[-1234] [ESB] [2019-03-04 19:27:23,359] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath} - 
Evaluation of the XPath expression syn:base64Decode(syn:get-property('cadena64')) resulted in an error 
net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathEvaluator.compile(XPathEvaluator.java:378) 
org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.evaluateDOMXPath(SynapseXPath.java:529) 
....
```

This gives us some information, but not as much as we would like. It tells us that the XPath expression was being evaluated by Saxon, and it tells us that Saxon was reporting a static error in the expression. It also tells us that it's a rather old release of Saxon, since in releases at least since Saxon 9.6, the class XPathEvaluator has contained around 330 lines. What it doesn't tell us is what the error actually is.

The poor diagnostics appear to be the responsibility of Apache synapse.

I'm afraid that's only a small step towards answering the question but I hope the information is useful to someone.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I was following this lead until the solution was posted :)

Answer (score 0):

your code works in ESB 5.0.0 so no help there (but upgrading would be a solution to your problem!)
I find it suspect though that Encode is working and Decode isn't. Could you try without `base64Decode` without `syn:`?